# How to get option VALUE from FORM without Submitting it in php?

Tags: javascript, php

here is the code.

```
<form method="POST"  onChange="getHouseModel()">
  <select name="house_model" id="house_model">
    <option value="">------</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $model1;?>">Model 1</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $model2;?>">Model 2</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $model3;?>">Model 3</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   function getHouseModel(){
      var model=$('#house_model').val();
      alert(model);
}
</script>
```

Now i want to show the value of model variable in php.how can i do this?

Comment: using ajax you can send any php file you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example jQuery and a ajax call like:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST"  onChange="getHouseModel()">
  <select name="house_model" id="house_model">
    <option value="">------</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $model1;?>">Model 1</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $model2;?>">Model 2</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $model3;?>">Model 3</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script>
$('#house_model').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php', 
        data: { house_model: $('#house_model').val() }, 
        cache: false, 
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

test.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
```

First we bind a chnage event to the selction field and in this we do a ajax call to the PHP file (test.php) with the value of the selection.

If you need only the selection you can remove the form around it is not needed for the ajax call ;)